# Max flow problem without splitting the flow from the supply nodes - LP formulation help

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, network-flow

Since max flow formulation can be easily solved using LP, I wanted to ask the following:

I am trying to solve a simple max flow problem where the graph is bipartite but with one added constraint. The constraint is that the flow from any supply node '$a$' should not be split, i.e. suppose I have a supply at node '$a$' of 4 units and have arcs $(a,x)$, $(a,y)$, and $(a,z)$, then the entire 4 units of supply should go through one and only one arc.

Is there an LP formulation for this? I can model it using integer variables....

Comment: this "all-or-nothing" constraint makes the problem hard, so there is no hope (in the complexity theory sense) that there is a reasonable LP formulation for this.

Answer (score 4):

Add binary variables $y_{ai}$ and the following constraints:
\begin{align}
y_{ax}+ y_{ay} + y_{za} &\le 1\\
x_{ai} &\le 4 y_{ai}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

If you define binary variables for each of the arcs let's say 
$$m_{ij} \ \ \forall i\in \text{supply}\ \ \text{and} \ \ j \in \text{demand}$$ then you can add the following constraint to the model:
$$\sum_j m_{ij} = 1$$
and the shipment then can be limited as the following ($M$ is a large number to relax $s_{ij}$ if necessary):
$$s_{ij} \le M \cdot m_{ij}$$
In this formulation $s_{ij}$ is still continuous variable